# ControlParameter is returning previous value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am trying to create a master/detail view. My `DetailsView` works correctly and on its own page, my `GridView` displaying my `EquipmentDataSource` works correctly as well. I can filter the `GridView` using `FilterParamaters`:

```
<FilterParameters>
    <%-- ControlParameter.Name will String.Formatted with the control's value --%>
    <asp:ControlParameter Type="String" Name='eEquipment.Contains("{0}")' ControlID="txtNumber" PropertyName="Text" />
</FilterParameters>
```

(I understand the dynamic Linq expression as the control name is bad design)

The problem comes into place when I try to filter based on on the key of the item that the `DetailsView` is showing. If I switch to an item who's PO# is 123, then 456, the `ControlParameter` will evaluate as 123. I think it may be fetching the value from the ViewState rather than what the control currently has, but I have no idea why.

Code:

```
<cc:ProcurementDataSource ID="dsProcurements" runat="server" />
<asp:DetailsView ID="dtvProcurements" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="dsProcurements" />
<cc:EquipmentDataSource ID="dsEquipment" runat="server">
    <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Type="String" Name='ePO == "{0}"' ControlID="dtvProcurements" PropertyName="DataItem.epClientPO" />
    </FilterParameters>
</cc:EquipmentDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsEquipment" />
```

I'm calling `Page.DataBind()` on `Page_Load`. I tried manually calling `DataBind()` on each control in case it was happening in a weird order,  but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was confused about whether `Control.DataBind()` was blocking or not.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoMapperConfiguration.Initialize();
    dtvProcurements.DataBind();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

doesn't work correctly while this does:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoMapperConfiguration.Initialize();
    dtvProcurements.DataBind();
}

protected void dtvProcurements_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```